# Angular 2 router `NavigationEnd` events before initialization

Tags: angular, ngrx

I want to display one of my angular components differently depending on the current route. To do this, I've set up a subscription to `NavigationEnd` in the component. However, this component only seems to be initialized after navigation has ended, so it is never called. Code is as follows:

```
constructor(private store: Store<fromApp.AppState>, private router: Router) {
}
subscribeToNavigation() {
  console.log('Setting up navigation subscription');
  const navEnd = this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(evt => evt instanceof NavigationEnd)
  ) as Observable<NavigationEnd>;
  this.navEndSubscription = navEnd.subscribe(evt => {
    console.log('Finished navigating to: ' + evt.url);
  });
  console.log('done');
}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way with listening to `NavigationEnd` events?

Comment: I can't really understand this. If you want to show that component once at begining differently then you can check url by ``this.router.url``. If you want change it over time when url changes you have url in ``evt.url``. Maybe I missed something - what's your problem?

Comment: yep! This is what I just found. thank you

Comment: yes me too.. if you put your NavigationEnd logic in the constructor it should work. However success in this case is to be tasted with skepticism as the addition of subscriptions to a constructor is not considered good practice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [is stated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52955137/angular-2-router-navigationend-events-before-initialization#comment92818715_52955137) any inital state changes can be done with `this.router.url`, and one can watch for further url changes using the subscription.